# Using conrep - Capturing and duplicating the BIOS settings

Tags: hp-proliant, configuration-management, bios

I got an HP ProLiant DL160SE G6, I need to capture the entire BIOS settings of one server and duplicate them to same model servers. This will save us lots of time and eliminate human errors.

I understand that it can be done using the `conrep` tool found in the SmartStart Scripting Toolkit.

I already downloaded the latest Toolkit version (SP51738) however I can't figure out how to make it work, I was hoping that someone here who have done that before can give me some guidelines and help me with the syntax.

I tried starting `conrep` from DOS but it seems that it's a 32-bit application. So I guess I will need to work with Windows PE. Maybe someone here can help me.